# How to update the time zone of gitlab?

Tags: database, timezone, rake, gitlab

The time in my gitlab's database is incorrect when I push one commit or create one merge request.
Then, from the GITLAB helps, it show that I need to update the time zone;
but when I update the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb from

```
 #gitlab_rails['time_zone'] = 'UTC'
```

to

```
#gitlab_rails['time_zone'] = 'Asia/Shanghai'
```

and run

```
#gitlab-ctl reconfigure
#gitlab-ctl restart
```

it does not work, the time in database is still incorrect (8 hours later, I am in shanghai UTC+8).
How to update the time zone of gitlab?

[image: the configure for time zone]

[image: the time in database]

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/timezone.html#changing-your-time-zone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to change GitLab timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175664/unable-to-change-gitlab-timezone)